# Laravel app keeps returning MethodNotAllowdHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, routes, semantic-ui

I've just made an app in Laravel running on Semantic UI, and when I run the program, it displays a MethodNotAllowedHttpException error. I have the code for the routes as displayed:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/view', [
    'uses' => 'ViewController@index',
    'as' => 'view'
 ]);

 Route::post('/login', [
    'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@login',
    'as' => 'login'
 ]);
```

The blade file also includes the 'method' and 'action' functions, as well. ` 
     @extends('layouts.app')

```
 @section('title')
    Login
 @endsection

 @section('content')
    @if(count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="ui bulleted list">
        @foreach($errors as $error)
            <div class="item">{{ $error }}</div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endif
<div class="ui middle aligned center aligned grid">
    <div class="column">
        <h2 class="ui teal header">
            <p>
                Log in to your account
            </p>
        </h2>
        <form class="ui large form" action="{{ route('login') }}" method="post">
            <div class="ui stacked segment">
                <div class="field">
                    <div class="ui left icon input">
                        <i class="user icon"></i>
                        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email">
                    </div>

                    <div class="ui left icon input">
                        <div class="ui left icon input">
                            <i class="lock"></i>
                            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="ui fluid large teal submit button">Login</div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="ui message">
            <p>
                New to us? <a href="#">Sign up</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection`
```

In my Auth folder, I also have the following code for the LoginController`

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request['email']], ['password' => $request['password']]))
    {
        return redirect()->route('view');
    }

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

My routes list shows that the routes are of post:

```
+--------+----------+----------+---------------+----------------------------
---------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI      | Name          | Action                                                
| Middleware   |
+--------+----------+----------+---------------+----------------------------
---------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /        |               | Closure                                               
| web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user |               | Closure                                               
| api,auth:api |
|        | POST     | login    | auth.login    | 
App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login       | web,guest    |
|        | POST     | register | auth.register | 
App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD | view     | view          | 
App\Http\Controllers\ViewController@index             | web          |
+--------+----------+----------+---------------+----------------------------
---------------------------+--------------+
```

Is there something that isn't typed correctly in the code? Can you use functions in the blade templating engine such as 'action' or 'method'?

Comment: when, where and how you encountered the error. And show the blade file.

Comment: I edited the question. I saw the error when testing the app and navigating to this page.

Comment: laravel's notfound execption is the route issue. When your request is not in the route, will  cause this issue. So which request your are send when you encounter this.

Comment: I use a POST request when I navigate to the page, and the action is for the login page. Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: I think what @KrisRoofe means is that you're making a `GET` request for the login, but your controller only supports the `POST` method, hence the _Http_ method error. I think, I'm not a Laravel developer.

Comment: Then how do I make a POST request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like so:

```
Route::get('login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'LoginController@index']);
Route::post('login', 'LoginController@login');
```

Comment: That seems to work. The program now lets me finish the authentication for users. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have created the correct route in your routes file.

```
  Route::get('/login', function(){
        return view('login');
  });
```

Comment: but I am not sure what the name of your view is.

Comment: The login is supposed to be a POST function for the route. BTW the name of the blade is login.

Comment: The GET request makes the program try to use the user data, giving me a different error. POST is how the route is supposed to work. How do I fix the route post function?

Comment: I think you would have both. A login POST route for doing your login. A login GET route for your login view. php artisan route:list and we can see your routes.

Comment: The route list displayed show that the routes are formatted as POST requests. They still send out as GET Requests though.

Comment: add what I posted and see how it effects the route list. You do not have a Get route to get the view for you login view.